# Trying to mute sampled sound

Tags: java, controls, mute, javax.sound.sampled

I'm having a problem adding MUTE control.

pardon me, I'm a beginner.

```
private BooleanControl muteControl;

private Clip audioClip;

public void load(String audioFilePath)
        throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException,
        LineUnavailableException {
    File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);

    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem
            .getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

    AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();

    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

    audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

    muteControl = (BooleanControl) audioClip.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE);

    audioClip.addLineListener(this);

    audioClip.open(ais);
}
```

The line `muteControl = (BooleanControl) audioClip.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE);`
keeps giving me an "IlligalArgumentException: Unsupported control type: Mute"

I've also tried using MASTER_GAIN control which gave me ""IlligalArgumentException: Unsupported control type: MASTER_GAIN"

Comment: according to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html#getControl(javax.sound.sampled.Control.Type)) getControl() wants a Control.Type as argument. Maybe you can try casting  BooleanControl.Type.MUTE to a Control.Type.

Comment: also tried using that, didn't quite change anything.